# Put fixed content to flex slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

Does anybody have idea how I can put content (div-menu) INSIDE (over sliding picture) my flex slide (li):

Flex slider default code:

```
<div class="wrapper_top">
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">

    <li>
    <img src="img/s1.jpg" />
    </li>

    <li>
    <img src="img/s2.jpg" />
    </li>


    </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

and I want put for example .willbemenu div. This is picture what i want: http://s7.postimg.org/5ul8zk1d7/WILLBE.jpg

```
.willbemenu{width: 1000px; background-color: orange; padding: 10px; text-align: center;}
```

I try this way and work, but problem is when flex slider make slide, I need willbemenu div FIXED without sliding.

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li style="background-image: url(img/s1.jpg);">
      <div class="willbemenu">Some option Some option</div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: So you just want it fixed on top of the slider? Why not just put it outside of it and fix it over it like you'd fix any other element? `position:fixed` then use `top` and `left` to put it where it needs to go

Comment: I tey, but problem is my .willbemenu div is 1000px width and I can't center it.

Comment: How is the slider positioned/given width? with that I could do it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a div outside positioned absolute;  You can use css tricks to center.

```
<style>
    .willbemenu{ width:1000px; background-color:orange; padding:10px; text-align:center; }
    .willbemenu{ position:absolute; top:10px; left:50%; margin-left:-500px; z-index:1; }
</style>

<div class="flexslider">
    <div class="willbemenu">Some menu stuff</div>

    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="img/s1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/s2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```